Would (almost all) neutrinos pass straight through a neutron star?
What percentage of them would not?

Depends on the neutron star and the neutrino: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/280586/how-much-of-neutrinos-pass-through-a-neutron-star
Propose to flag as duplicate, if possible.

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/48135/what-does-it-mean-for-a-proto-neutron-star-to-be-opaque-to-neutrinos

https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1476/neutrino-interaction-with-dense-molecular-structures

@SpaceCore You need to look on site for duplicates.

Please don't do that. Your question needs to make sense independently, and not be a continuation of the title. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173271/334566 & links therein.
